# Android Automated Script Pause for Emulator Load Time

Tags: android, scripting, ant, batch-file, apk

I've been tasked with creating a completely automated script that will allow the user to create a new sd card, emulator, start said emulator, build a debug apk, and finally install said apk on the emulator just created.

So far, I've accomplished this through the use of Windows batch files, which has worked completely fine, aside from one problem I can't seem to figure out a workaround for.  That is, after the...

```
emulator -avd %emuName%
```

...command has been run, the batch file will immediately begin building the debug .apk file, and then begin installing it once built.  The problem occurs when the debug .apk file build process finishes prior to the emulator fully loading.  To temporarily solve this, I have added in a pause which calls for the user to press enter once the emulator is fully loaded; however, I would like to remove this.

One way I've thought to solve this is to add a predetermined length pause into the script, however, the build times range anywhere from 50 seconds to as high as 95 seconds at times, so this isn't a very effective way of handling the issue.

Is there any way I can force the batch script to wait until the emulator is fully loaded prior to attempting to install the apk to the emulator?  If not, what may be some other ways to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
  adb wait-for-device          - block until device is online
```

to wait for the AVD.